# How do I copy .html file from delta location into blob storage in Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to move file from delta location into blob storage, And also if it possible to display same html file in databricks it would be great.

How do I display HTML content stored in delta location in databricks?

Comment: what is the delta location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your delta location is in dbfs, First set up account key and configure the storage account to access.

```py
storage_account_name = "Storage account name"
storage_account_access_key = "storage account acesss key"

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",storage_account_access_key)
```

then move/copy file from delta location to blob storage. To move file, we use `dbutils.fs.mv` and to copy we use `dbutils.fs.cp` commands

```py
dbutils.fs.mv('path of file','wasbs://<container name>@<Storage account name>".blob.core.windows.net//sample2.html')
```

**Execution:**
[image]

**copied file:**
[image]